# Excel macros can only use VBA to write? What about java?

Tags: java, vba, excel

I need to write a script by using an Excel macro, but my VBA is so poor. Is it possible to write the script in Java or other languages?

Comment: It's VBA, not VB.Net for macros in Excel.

Comment: If you need it for interacting with the user, the answers below are right. If you need it only for processing data, then you can choose any other solution that has some excel plugin/driver. Java, .Net or even SSIS or Talend Open Studio. So what's the purpose of that script?

Comment: as Laszlo stated, if you want to edit the data in the excel doc, run formulas, or whatever, you can do it outside of xl, but if you want buttons and clicks/actions, its VBA only.  Also note, that Mac support for VBA is slightly different then windows. http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac.htm

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use any other language except VBA to write macros for MS Office.

Answer (score 1):

You could always write a .dll, if your language of choice supports such compiling, then link to the functions within using VBA. This way, you would not need to learn much VBA to make it work. However, this would also mean the project might become more difficult to maintain.

For example, using the standard Windows `User32.dll`:

```
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal HWND As Long) As Long
```

(See [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa165080%28v=office.10%29.aspx) for more info on usage, etc.)